# getting NullPointerException when inflating a view for dialogView

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-alertdialog

In the process of creating a dialog view I am getting this error:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 26135
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:825)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:828)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:523)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:425)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:368)
                  at com.example.myapp.NewGameActivity.createTeam(NewGameActivity.java:145)
                  at com.example.myapp.NewGameActivity.onItemSelected(NewGameActivity.java:394)
                  at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:917)
                  at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchOnItemSelected(AdapterView.java:906)
                  at android.widget.AdapterView.access$300(AdapterView.java:51)
                  at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:876)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

This is my code which causes the exception:

```
final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout_add_team, rootView);
```

More Code for context:

```
 //Dialog
    // 1. Instantiate an AlertDialog.Builder with its constructor
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(NewGameActivity.this);

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    ViewGroup rootView = findViewById(R.id.root_new_game);
    final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout_add_team, rootView);
// 2. Chain together various setter methods to set the dialog characteristics
    builder
            .setTitle(R.string.new_team)
            .setView(dialogView)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.done, null)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    // User cancelled the dialog
                }
            });

    // 3. Get the AlertDialog from create()
    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
            Button button = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // User clicked OK button

                        //Dismiss once everything is OK.
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
```

I also tried using null (caused same error):

```
final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout_add_team, null);
```

Adding the attachToRoot value did not change the error:

```
final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout_add_team, null, false);
```

**UPDATE:** the dialog_layout_add_team.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/root_add_team_dialog_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="8dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/enter_a_team_title"
    android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/team_title_edit_text_add_team"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/team_title" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/add_players"
    android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/current_players_text_view_add_team"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/current_players" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/player_number_edit_text_add_team"
        android:layout_weight="80"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/player_number"
        android:inputType="number" />
    <view
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="20"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/player_name_edit_text_add_team"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="80"
        android:hint="@string/player_name" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/add_player_imageButton_add_team"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_person_add_white_24dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: post the dialog_layout_add_team.xml

Comment: Ok, I have added the file

Comment: ViewGroup rootView = findViewById(R.id.root_new_game); this is making the rootView null brother! please give the whole code of this page! where is root_new_gameView?

Comment: it is the root view of the activity

Comment: You have a lowercase-`v` `<view>` element without a `class` attribute in your layout. You apparently meant to use uppercase-`V` `<View>` instead, as it looks like it's just a spacer.

Comment: Thank you @MikeM. this solved my problem. If you want to leave it as your answer I would accept and upvote it.